# How can I find the directory where my application is located using VB6?

Tags: file, vb6, copy

I'm in folder **ABC** and inside I have file: *notes.txt*
I want to be able to copy *notes.txt* from my folder **ABC** to folder **XYZ** on **D:\XYZ**

So when program is compiled and let's say I press COPY button it won't matter where folder **ABC** is placed on C:\ M:\ or K:\  - it always will look into folder **ABC** where program is executed and it will copy *notes.txt* to some other path/destination

I'm using VB6

Thank you!

I tried using Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Something like that:

fso.CopyFile "L:\ABC\notes.txt, "D:\XYZ"

But I don't want to depend on the path for **ABC** folder

Comment: Show us what you have as of yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`App.Path` provides the path from where the EXE has been executed. This should even work with network paths like `\\ABCD\EFG\notes.txt`

This should do it

```
fso.CopyFile App.Path & "\ABC\notes.txt", "D:\XYZ"
```